# Método String.equals e NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, comparação

Apesar da dúvida ser bem básica, gostaria de entender porque o `equals` neste caso:

```
    String texto = null;

    System.out.println("teste".equals(texto));
```

Retorna `false` normalmente(exemplo no [ideone](https://ideone.com/cLtQDc)), mas no exemplo abaixo:

```
    String texto = null;

    System.out.println(texto.equals(""));
```

Ele estoura a exceção `NullPointerException`, como pode ser visto também no [ideone](https://ideone.com/POHZq1).

Em ambos os casos há uma comparação com `null`, mas o retorno é diferente conforme o lado em que o `null` é passado, por quê ocorre isso?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acontece que o `NullPointerException` só vai estourar quando você tentar acessar algum elemento (entenda por elemento um método ou atributo)  de um objeto que seja nulo.

Veja, no seu exemplo

```
String texto = null;
System.out.println("teste".equals(texto));
```

Aqui você está acessando/chamando o método `equals` da `string` literal **teste** (que não é um objeto nulo, por óbvio - `"teste"` é um objeto do tipo `String`) e está passando `null` por parâmetro, logo, você não está tentando acessar nenhum elemento de um objeto nulo.

```
String texto = null;
System.out.println(texto.equals(""));
```

Já aqui, você está acessando/chamando o método `equals` da variável `texto` (que é um objeto nulo).

Answer (score 4):

A diferença é que no primeiro caso você está criando um objeto do tipo *String*, cujo seu valor é igual a `teste`. Logo em seguida você chama o método `equals()` desse objeto. Como argumento, você está passando nulo ao invés de um objeto.

No segundo caso não existe objeto, ou seja, a variável `texto` não referencia objeto algum, portanto quando você tenta acessar o método `equals()` a variável `texto` retorna nulo e lança uma exceção de NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3):

Quando você faz isso `System.out.println("teste".equals(texto));` você está chamando o método equals em uma string literal e comparando ela com null e o que naturalmente é falso.

Quando você isso `System.out.println(texto.equals(""));` você está chamando o método equals de a partir de um objeto `null`, o que não é valido, levantando assim o famoso `NullPointerException`.