# Como criar um método em um Array de JButtons que altera a cor do jButton com ActionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton

Estou fazendo um projeto que requer a criação de uma ferramenta lápis que irá pintar um grupo de `jButtons` posicionados em `gridLayout` (10x10) como se fossem pixels.

Criei um método chamado 'colorButton' para alterar a cor do `JButton` de acordo com a ferramenta (lápis ou balde) e a cor do lápis selecionado (existem outros 10 `jButtons` coloridos que determinam a cor ), sendo necessário escolher a ferramenta e a cor e em seguida o pixel (`jButton`) que será pintado.

Para isso criei duas variáveis globais que são alteradas de acordo com a tipo de ferramenta (lápis ou balde de tinta) e cor (10 cores diferentes) selecionado, chamadas tipo e cor.

O problema ocorre que, ao invés de chamar um `ActionPerformed` para cada um dos 100 `jButtons` do `gridLayout` para aplicar o método 'colorButton', criei um novo método para a criação dos 100 `jButtons` para que o método 'colorButton' seja aplicado para cada um deles, porém preciso que este método somente seja aplicado caso o `jButton` seja clicado, ou seja, que tenha o mesmo efeito do `ActionPerformed`.

Segue abaixo um trecho de meu código

```
public class ColorirRegioesGraficas extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form ColorirRegioesGraficas
 */
public ColorirRegioesGraficas() {
    initComponents();

}
//Método que cria os 100 jButtons dentro de um panel e atribui o método de cor para cada um deles.

public void criaPixel(){ 
    JButton[] button = new JButton[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    button[i] = new JButton();       
    pnlPixels.add(button[i]);
    colorButton(button[i]);         
    }       
}
//Método de cor que altera a cor de um jButton de acordo com a cor selecionada.

public void colorButton(JButton button){ 
    if (tipo.equals("lapis")){ //Preciso de algo que funcione como um if(button.actionPerformed.isTrue)
        switch (cor) {
            case "cinza":
                button.setBackground( new Color(101,101,101));
                break;
            case "branco":
                button.setBackground( new Color(255,255,255));
                break;
            case "preto":
                button.setBackground( new Color(0,0,0));
                break;
            case "azulE":
                button.setBackground( new Color(0,0,255));
                break;
            case "vermelho":
                button.setBackground( new Color(255,0,0));
                break;
            case "verde":
                button.setBackground( new Color(0,204,0));
                break;
            case "amarelo":
                button.setBackground( new Color(255,255,0));
                break;
            case "laranja":
                button.setBackground( new Color(255,204,0));
                break;
            case "rosa":
                button.setBackground( new Color(255,153,153));
                break;
            case "azulC":
                button.setBackground( new Color(0,204,204));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

String cor; // É determinada ao clicar em um dos jButtons coloridos
String tipo; // É determinado ao clicar em um dos jButtons com ferramentas
```

Neste caso, jogaria a chamada do método criaPixel() dentro de cada `jButton` colorido, pois as variáveis cor e tipo já estariam definidas e o método funcionaria adequadamente, porém preciso saber como verificar se o botão foi clicado para aplicar o método colorButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, bastaria você criar uma classe que implemente [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), e atribuir a todos os botões. A classe poderia ser assim:

```
class AcaoBotaoColoridoListener implements ActionListener {

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
  if ("lapis".equals(tipo)) { 
   switch (cor) {
    case "cinza":
     button.setBackground(new Color(101, 101, 101));
     break;
    case "branco":
     button.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
     break;
    case "preto":
     button.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
     break;
    case "azulE":
     button.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 255));
     break;
    case "vermelho":
     button.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
     break;
    case "verde":
     button.setBackground(new Color(0, 204, 0));
     break;
    case "amarelo":
     button.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 0));
     break;
    case "laranja":
     button.setBackground(new Color(255, 204, 0));
     break;
    case "rosa":
     button.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 153));
     break;
    case "azulC":
     button.setBackground(new Color(0, 204, 204));
     break;
    default:
     break;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Depois basta aplicar a cada botão, usando o mesmo laço que você já usa para criar os botões:

```
JButton[] button = new JButton[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
button[i] = new JButton();       
pnlPixels.add(button[i]);
button[i].addActionListener(new AcaoBotaoColoridoListener());         
}
```

Obs.: inverti a comparação do seu if para `"lapis".equals(tipo)`, pois assim, caso `tipo` chegue nulo, evita-se problemas com [NullPointerException em comparações de Strings](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119426/28595).

---

## Atualização

Há uma forma mais "elegante" de fazer isso, que é utilizando `Map` para guardar as cores, assim você não precisa fazer um `swith...case` com tanta opção assim.

Primeiro crie uma variável do tipo `Map` onde a chave será a string com os nomes das cores, e o valor será as cores propriamente ditas:

```
private Map<String, Color> colorMap;

(...)

colorMap = new HashMap<String, Color>();
colorMap.put("cinza", new Color(101, 101, 101));
colorMap.put("branco", new Color(255, 255, 255));
colorMap.put("preto", new Color(0, 0, 0));
colorMap.put("azulE", new Color(0, 0, 255));
colorMap.put("vermelho", new Color(255, 0, 0));
colorMap.put("verde", new Color(0, 204, 0));
colorMap.put("amarelho", new Color(255, 255, 0));
colorMap.put("laranja", new Color(255, 204, 0));
colorMap.put("rosa", new Color(255, 153, 153));
colorMap.put("azulC", new Color(0, 204, 204));
```

Depois basta verificar se a cor existe no `Map` e definir a cor para o botão. Veja como a classe ficou:

```
class AcaoBotaoColoridoListener implements ActionListener {

    private Map<String, Color> colorMap;

    public AcaoBotaoColoridoListener() {

        colorMap = new HashMap<String, Color>();
        colorMap.put("cinza", new Color(101, 101, 101));
        colorMap.put("branco", new Color(255, 255, 255));
        colorMap.put("preto", new Color(0, 0, 0));
        colorMap.put("azulE", new Color(0, 0, 255));
        colorMap.put("vermelho", new Color(255, 0, 0));
        colorMap.put("verde", new Color(0, 204, 0));
        colorMap.put("amarelho", new Color(255, 255, 0));
        colorMap.put("laranja", new Color(255, 204, 0));
        colorMap.put("rosa", new Color(255, 153, 153));
        colorMap.put("azulC", new Color(0, 204, 204));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if ("lapis".equals(tipo) && colorMap.containsKey(cor)) {
            button.setBackground(colorMap.get(cor));
        }
    }
}
```

Perceba que agora o código ficou mais legível e mais fácil de dar manutenção.

Comment: Criei a classe e apliquei da mesma forma como está mostrado, porém ocorreu em erro de "Cannot find Symbol" em `AcaoBotaoColoridoListener()`  dentro do laço de criação de botões.

Como correção sugerida, é criado um método 
`private ActionListener AcaoBotaoColoridoListener() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");`

Comment: @Devikn editei, falou um New ali dentro do for.

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Não havia me atentado ao pequeno detalhe do `new`. Com sua classe devidamente implementada removi a chamada do método `criaPixel` de  cada `jButton` colorido e coloquei novamente junto à inicialização do projeto, pois agora as variáveis não serão nulas sendo feitas as comparações das variáveis globais somente após o `actionPerformed` de cada `jButton` ser acionado, o que ocorrerá somente após as variáveis terem recebido as Strings equivalentes. Funcionou conforme o desejado, muito obrigado!