# Como diferenciar botões dentro do mesmo evento?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Eu gostaria de saber um método para diferenciar um botão que gerou evento, no meu método que vai tratar os eventos.

No exemplo abaixo eu adiciono a mesma classe que trata os eventos a 2 botões, mas não consigo diferenciar os botões no meu método `actionPerformed()`;

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            JFrame f = new JFrame();

            JButton b1 = new JButton("B1");
            JButton b2 = new JButton("B2");
            ActionListener evento = new Eventos();

            b1.addActionListener(evento);
            b2.addActionListener(evento);
            f.getContentPane().add(b1);
            f.getContentPane().add(b2);

            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(300,400);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
            f.pack();
        }
    }

    class Eventos implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // diferenciar b1 do b2;
            System.out.println("Clique");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma simples é definir *Action Commands* utilizando o método [`setActionCommand()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#setActionCommand-java.lang.String-):

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("B1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("B2");

ActionListener evento = new Eventos();

b1.setActionCommand("botao1");
b1.setActionCommand("botao2");

b1.addActionListener(evento);
b2.addActionListener(evento);

(...)

class Eventos implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String action = e.getActionCommand();

        switch(action) {
            case "botao1":
                //Ação do botao 1
            break;
            case "botao2":
                //Ação do botao 2
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

A vantagem em utilizar *action command* ao invés de `button.getText()` é que você pode alterar livremente o texto dos botões sem ter que ficar atualizando o listener. Lembrando que esta opção não está restrita a somente 2 botões, podem ser adicionados outros, só vai ter que adicionar `case` no `switch`, mas em caso de muitos botões, há soluções melhores para se identificar os botoes do que usando switch, [**nesta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134554/28595) tem um exemplo usando `HashMap`.